# iOS - changing the size of the masterViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I am using `Xcode` `UISplitViewController` default template to create an application.

My app will be landscape only.

I would like to make the `masterViewController` wider... 400 px, for example. I want it to be always that width.

I do this on the `initWithNib`.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Cars", @"");
        self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
        self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(400.0, 600.0);
    }
    return self;
}
```

But it continues to be 320 px wide, as created by the template.

As far as I googled around, this seems impossible to do. Is this really impossible to change the width of the `masterViewController` when shown in landscape (in popover ?)

I have also tried to add this in a `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` without success:

```
[self setContentSizeForViewInPopover:CGSizeMake(400.0, 600.0)];
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using the built in splitviewcontroller. I would recommend looking up "MGSplitViewController" which will have the functionality you are looking for

Comment: I tested MGSplitViewController. It is almost similar, but it is too big to what I want and it is not 100% similar. When in landscape it will not show the master view over the detail view. It will only show in a classical popup with the arrow pointing to the button... almost there. Anyway, I have accepted your answer because I don't see how it can be done using the regular controller... thanks.